# Apache Camel SSL RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

Folks,
  Apache-Camel does not seem to support AMQPs when connecting to Rabbit.  Does anyone know if this is somewhere in the pipeline to be built?

When attempting all connections, we get this in Rabbit logs:

```
error on AMQP connection <0.30060.4>: {ssl_upgrade_error,timeout} (unknown POSIX error)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Current RabbitMQ Camel Component does not support any SSL configuration features. Also, if you take a look to their JIRA it seems there is no ticket open for implementing this ([Camel Jira for RabbitMQ Tickets](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7003?jql=project%20=%20CAMEL%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open,%20%22In%20Progress%22,%20Reopened%29%20AND%20text%20~%20%22RabbitMQ%22))

You can fill a ticket or, even better, you could modify the existent component to support SSL and donate it to the open source community. If you plan to do this, please read [Apache Camel: Contributing](http://camel.apache.org/contributing.html)