# Why isn't my connection working over SSL?

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am trying to use apache camel (camel-spring-boot - 2.20.2) with rabbitmq and create routes.

It does work fine when I use un-secured RabbitMQ (no-SSL), but when I try to connect to RabbitMQ using SSL, it's not connecting to the queue at all.
I am using "connectionFactory" option given on Apache Camel page. This connectionFactory object has all the correct parameters set (useSslProtocol, username, password etc).

Please note that the connectionFactory is properly populated, as I am able to use it to connect using the other way (setting it in setConnectionFactory on SimpleMessageListenerContainer). But with Apache Camel I am facing issues.

> ```
> java.io.IOException: null
>   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:116) ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
>   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:112) ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
>   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:360)
> ```
>
> ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
>         at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
>   ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
>       Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
>         at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
>   ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
>       *
>       *
>       Caused by: java.io.EOFException
>         at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>         at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91) ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]

While browsing more, I came across this question: 
[Apache Camel SSL RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332129/apache-camel-ssl-rabbitmq), but this seems to be a bit old, so may not be relevant anymore.

Please advise. This has become a show-stopper for us.

---

I made some changes… I realized that I was not using the connectionFactory in the URL correctly -
Followed this link - [How to set two RabbitMQ connections for the same Camel RouteBuilder configure method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263407/how-to-set-two-rabbitmq-connections-for-the-same-camel-routebuilder-configure-me) and could move ahead…. But now, I am getting this ( looks like I made some progress, but still facing the below ).

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_161]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_161]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_161]    at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_161]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_161]    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_161]    at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)
>   ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]  at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:918)
>   ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]  at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:870)
>   ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]  at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:828)
>   ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]  at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:996)
>   ~[amqp-client-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]  at
>   org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEndpoint.connect(RabbitMQEndpoint.java:248)
>   ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.20.2.jar!/:2.20.2]     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.openConnection(RabbitMQConsumer.java:64)
>   ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.20.2.jar!/:2.20.2]     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.getConnection(RabbitMQConsumer.java:75)
>   ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.20.2.jar!/:2.20.2]     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitConsumer.(RabbitConsumer.java:55)
>   [camel-rabbitmq-2.20.2.jar!/:2.20.2]  at
>   org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.createConsumer(RabbitMQConsumer.java:120)
>   [camel-rabbitmq-2.20.2.jar!/:2.20.2]

Route looks like below -
connectionFactory object is populated correctly. Its being used in the application and working ( uses regular Spring way of connecting to RabbitMQ )

> final CamelContext camelContext = getContext(); final
>   org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry registry = new
>   org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry(); final
>   org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry compositeRegistry = new
>   org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry();
>   compositeRegistry.addRegistry(camelContext.getRegistry());
>   compositeRegistry.addRegistry(registry);
>   ((org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext)
>   camelContext).setRegistry(compositeRegistry);
>   registry.put("connectionFactoryWorker", connectionFactory);
>
> from("rabbitmq::5671/?queue=&connectionFactory=#connectionFactoryWorker").log("received
>   message");

Comment: How does your connectionFactory look? Can you share your route code?

Comment: Just added some details above.

Comment: Did you enable the property sslProtocol? See the camel-rabbitmq documentation.

Comment: yeah .. from("rabbitmq::5671/<exchange>?sslProtocol=true&queue=<queue>&connectionFactory=#connectionFactoryWorker").log("received message");

Comment: the above did not work either

Comment: i even tried - sslProtocol=TLS,  but same error.  When i printed rabbitMQSSLContext.getSSLContext().getProtocol(), it gives me "TLSv1.2" .

Comment: Suggest you take it Camel's gitter space to ask Camel users.

Comment: Hi @user2931444 , I too faced similar problem . I fixed by retrieving to older version  .I uploaded my findings in below link ; It might useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546431/camel-rabbitmq-component-unable-to-communicate-via-ssl